# Calling a Method in a Loop Error

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, constructor, while-loop

I am trying to call the animated in the while loop using the following API:

```
public void animate( String currentTransaction, double currentAmount, double currentBalance )
```

I am trying to make the call using this:

```
animate(  currentTransaction, currentAmount, currentBalance );
```

However, I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

The errors are:

```
currentTransaction cannot be resolved to a variable and
currentBalance cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Posted below is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Accounting extends JFrame {
 private BankAccount bankAccount;

 public Accounting() {
   bankAccount = new BankAccount( getBackground() );
   setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
   setSize( 300, 300 );
   setVisible( true );
 }

 public void balanceCheckBook( ) {
    double balance;
    double currentAmount;
    String nextLine;
    StringTokenizer st;
    String transactionName;
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
         scan = new Scanner (new FileReader("transactions.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner callParse;
    String trans;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        trans = scan.nextLine();
        scan.useDelimiter(":");
        callParse = new Scanner(trans);
        callParse.useDelimiter(":");
    }
    try {
        scan = new Scanner (new FileReader("checkbook.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner callParse2;
    String check;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        check = scan.nextLine();
        scan.useDelimiter(":");
        callParse2 = new Scanner(check);
        callParse2.useDelimiter(":");
    }

    animate(  currentTransaction, currentAmount, currentBalance );
 }

 public void animate( String currentTransaction, double currentAmount, double currentBalance ) {
    // set the current transaction in the bankAccount object
    if ( currentTransaction.startsWith( "Ch" ) )
        bankAccount.setCurrentTransaction( new Check(currentAmount ) );
    else if ( currentTransaction.startsWith( "With" ) )
        bankAccount.setCurrentTransaction( new Withdrawal(currentAmount ) );
    else if ( currentTransaction.startsWith( "Dep" ) )
        bankAccount.setCurrentTransaction( new Deposit(currentAmount ) );
    else
        bankAccount.setCurrentTransaction( new UnknownTransaction(currentAmount ) );
    // set the currentBalance data member in the bankAccount object
    bankAccount.updateBalance( currentBalance );

    repaint( );
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 3000 );  // wait for the animation to finish
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
    }
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    super.paint( g );
    bankAccount.draw( g );
}

public static void main( String [] args ) {
    Accounting app = new Accounting( );
    app.balanceCheckBook( );
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post it?

Comment: Could you send error?

Comment: `currentTransaction` is not defined

Comment: @Smit Edited my question with the error. Sorry.

Comment: @UğurARTUN Edited my question with the error. Sorry.

Comment: @StackP Exception giving you exact deatils. However you can look for others answers and comment by @ nachokk

Answer (score 3):

The variable `currentTransaction` does not exist in the scope of your function `balanceCheckBook`.  If that is the case, you need to either pass a variable to function `balanceCheckBook` or create a member variable within the class named `currentTransaction`.

In other words, when you invoke the function `animate` in function `balanceCheckBook` with variable `currentTransaction` undefined, the compiler will never know which value you are going to pass to the function `animate`.

```
animate(  currentTransaction, currentAmount, currentBalance );
```

Therefore, you need to define `currentTransaction` and make Java knows what value to pass.

Answer (score 0):

`currentTransaction` is not defined within the scope of the method and neither it is a parameter to the method. You need to either pass the variable as argument or make it an instance variable .The method declared as :

```
public void animate( String currentTransaction, double currentAmount, 
                     double currentBalance )
```

Hence you need to call it with a `String`,a `double` and another `double` : `animate(String, double ,double)` , while you call it as `animate(  currentTransaction, currentAmount, currentBalance );` but I don't see where have you defined `currentTransaction` or `currentBalance`.

Comment: How would I pass the variable as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you should use variables `balance` instead of `currentBalance` and `trans` or `transactionName` instead of `currentTransaction`.